# Check if a function is virtual

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to check if a function is virtual or not from the Eclipse CDT's AST?

I tried to perform this kind of check by using a visitor on the *ICPPASTFunctionDeclarator* node. It has the following methods: *isOverride()*, *isPureVirtual()*, *isFinal()*, etc. Something like *isVirtual()* is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ grammar has some oddities. One of them is that the *function declarator* production only covers the part of a function declaration starting from the function name (technically, it also includes any *pointer operators* from the function return type which precede the function name), and ending at the end of the function declaration (or the start of the function body).

The function's return type (again, except for *pointer operators*) and other specifiers that go at the beginning of the declaration (including `virtual`) are part of a sibling node called the *decl-specifier*.

So, if your starting point is a *function declarator*, you have to navigate to the *decl-specifier* via its parent. The parent can be either a *simple declaration* (in case of a function declaration without a body) or a *function definition* (declaration with body), and you have to check for each case.

Once you have the *decl-specifier*, you can check for virtual using `ICPPASTDeclSpecifier.isVirtual()`.

In code:

```
// declarator is your ICPPASTFunctionDeclarator
ICPPASTDeclSpecifier declSpec = null;
if (declarator.getParent() instanceof IASTSimpleDeclaration) {
    declSpec = (ICPPASTDeclSpecifier) ((IASTSimpleDeclaration) declarator.getParent()).getDeclSpecifier();
} else if (declarator.getParent() instanceof IASTFunctionDefinition) {
    declSpec = (ICPPASTDeclSpecifier) ((IASTFunctionDefinition) declarator.getParent()).getDeclSpecifier();
}
if (declSpec != null) {
    boolean isVirtual = declSpec.isVirtual();
}
```

---

Finally, note that what the above tells you is whether the `virtual` keyword appears in the function's declaration.

A function can be virtual without the `virtual` keyword appearing in its declaration, if it's a function in a derived class overriding a virtual function in a base class.

If what you really want to know is whether the function is virtual, even if the `virtual` keyword is not used, that's more involved. I don't think there's an easy way to do it using CDT's public APIs, but it gets easier if you're willing to use internal APIs. Let me know if you're interested in that, I can provide more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. I think that I will survive with your first solution because I need to detect at least the top-level virtual function (which is always possible). I am not sure If I can use the internal API because I'm relaying on Codan's *visit(...)* methods, so I guess that CDT's public API is the only way to do that. Can you tell me is there any AST viewer available for CDT AST?

Comment: @temp35234: There isn't a built-in AST viewer in CDT. There is a set of extensions in [this repo](https://github.com/IFS-HSR/ch.hsr.ifs.cdttesting) which includes an AST viewer, but I've never tried it.